# How to navigate to a single child directory without knowing its name using shell command?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to run a script in a remote machine from my JAVA code using runCommand() method. Now I can't always know the full path of the script as a particular directory name keeps changing. For example the path looks like this : ***/a/b/xxxxx/script*** . **xxxx** is the directory name that keeps changing and its the only single directory under /a/b/. Is there any shell command using which I can get the directory name ? I know using JAVA,but I specifically need shell command.

Comment: find /a/b -type d  -maxdepth 1 should give you the name of the directories in the directory b. If you are sure its going to be just one, just store the output in a variable and then go ahead with your processing.

Comment: This should do the job: `dirname /a/b/*/script`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only a single self-directory, another fool-proof way of doing it would be

```
cd */.
```

`*/.` is that this expands to the "self directory" (named .) in any subdirectory, which is of course the sub-directory itself. Refer the below example of how it works.

E.g.

```
$ pwd
/home/dude/
$ mkdir -p a/b/ldsnds/c
$ cd a/b/*/.
$ pwd
/home/dude/a/b/ldsnds
$ cd -
/home/dude/
$ cd a/b/*/./c
$ pwd
/home/dude/a/b/ldsnds/c
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should give you the name of the directory in the directory "b".

```
 $ find /a/b  -type d  -maxdepth 1 2> /dev/null
```

If you are so sure that it would always be one directory in /a/b then just store the output of find in a variable and move ahead.

Note: 2> /dev/null is just to get rid of errorneous warnings.